# Combining multiple columsn into one

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

i have the following dataframe:

```
 Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
0 value1 x1      y1       na     na 
1 value2 x2      y2       na     na
2 value3 x3      na       z1     na
3 value4 x4      na       z2     na
4 value5 x5      na       na     w1
```

I want the following

```
 Column1 Column2 Column
0 value1 x1      y1 
1 value2 x2      y2
2 value3 x3      z1
3 value4 x4      z2
4 value5 x5      w1
```

How can I achieve this? It seems that stack() doesn't works for this task.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Hey, why are you getting that kind of data? Maybe if you share the previous step there is a way to fix that.

Comment: I'll do later, since im short of time right now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the initial columns as index, then back fill on axis 1 and select the first column:

```
cols = ['Column1','Column2']
out = df.mask(df.eq('na')).set_index(cols).bfill(axis=1,).iloc[:,0].reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0  value1      x1      y1
1  value2      x2      y2
2  value3      x3      z1
3  value4      x4      z2
4  value5      x5      w1
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with `coalesce` from `pyjanitor` to abstract the process(under the hood, it's just bfill/ffill):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.coalesce('Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5').dropna(axis=1)

  Column1 Column2 Column3
0  value1      x1      y1
1  value2      x2      y2
2  value3      x3      z1
3  value4      x4      z2
4  value5      x5      w1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_column = pd.Series()
for col in ["Column3", "Column4", "Column5"]:
    new_column = pd.concat([new_column, df[col].dropna()])
    df = df.drop(col, axis=1)
df["Column3"] = new_column
```

```
>>> df
    Column1 Column2 Column3
0   value1  x1  y1
1   value2  x2  y2
2   value3  x3  z1
3   value4  x4  z2
4   value5  x5  w1
```